# Bind non-project files to tfs source control?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs

Is it possible to have non-project/non-solution-related files automatically bound to TFS source control?

I am using Visual Studio. I have created some folders under my solution folder to which I would like to add logs, scripts, etc. The files are created by code and put in the correct folder, but they are not added to source control unless I manually go to Source Control Explorer and manually click to "Add Items to Folder."

I am trying to keep these files separate from projects. In a sense, I am trying to use TFS like Dropbox, where it automatically adds new items to pending changes.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a local workspace instead of a server workspace:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx

Specifically the "Why should I use a local workspace?" section refers to changes being picked up automatically when added or deleted outside of Visual Studio.  Please be aware of the differences between local and server workspaces if you decided to switch as there are some trade-offs between them.

Once using a local workspace, any files added to folder should show up in the workspace's Excluded Changes area as "Detected: (x) add(s)".

[image]

If you click on this link and choose "Promoted" the changes are added.

Comment: I'm already using a local workspace. The files are not automatically added to tfs source control when added to the folder. I need to use Source Control Explorer to add them manually.

I have tried using code to add the items to the pending list. However, I cannot seem to access the workspace that is set up in Visual Studio. I can create a new workspace, but then I can't map it to the correct location since the correct workspace is already mapped there.